# Notify a content resolver when normal sql insert or update

Tags: android

I have created a small content provider (which I only use to query a db table and fetch some value).  I have confirmed that the provider works fine.

The table values get updated on a regular basis through normal sql insertions(and not through anycontent provider)

Whenever an insert/update or delete occurs through a normal sqlite operation as mentioned above, I need to notify the content resolvers which was written to communicate with the content provider just for quering database and fetch some values.

Is this, possible? If yes what need to be done?

Any help is appreciated.

EDITED to include my DB insert method:

```
public void insert(ArrayList<Integer> profileValues, String tableName){
    String duplicationCheck = " WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM profiles WHERE devID = "+"'"+profileValues.get(0)+"'"+");";
    if(tableName.equals(PROFILES_TABLE)){
        profilesDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                PROFILES_TABLE +
                "(devID,alert,findme,proximity,timep,conn_status) SELECT "+"'"+profileValues.get(0)+"'"+","+profileValues.get(1)+","+profileValues.get(2)+","+profileValues.get(3)+","+profileValues.get(4)+","+profileValues.get(5)+duplicationCheck);
    }
    getContentResolver().notifyChange(MY_CONTENT_URI, null);

 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Any time you manually update the underlying database and need to notify registered `ContentObserver` instances, call `notifyChange()` on the `ContentResolver` present for the `Context`.

So, for instance, let's say you had registered a `ContentObserver` with the constant value `MY_CONTENT_URI`:

```
//Insert, update, or delete data in the database

//If you are within a Context, like Activity or Service
getContentResolver().notifyChange(MY_CONTENT_URI, null);

//Otherwise pass in a Context you can call on
context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(MY_CONTENT_URI, null);
```

All registered observers for the particular `Uri` you pass will be notified.

Comment: just to re-confirm. It is not mandatory that the db updation happens through content provider insert/update or delete , correct? notifyChange can be included even after a simple db insert query, correct?

Comment: Yes.  Regardless of how and where you update your custom database, you would need to call these methods manually; even in the case where you were implementing your own `ContentProvider`.  The framework doesn't do this under the hood for you in any case.

Comment: I have edited the question to show my db insertion. The way in which I have used the notify method is correct? Also, I need to write ContentObserver(in order for getting update notifications) class wherever I make use of this content uri, correct?

Comment: That's correct, `notifyChange()` will trigger updates only on each `ContentObserver` that is registered with the same `Uri`.

Comment: What about when my underlying database loads data from an external source (Json) in a separate thread? Is it possible to notify from there a contentprovider that data has changed in the database?